# Saving Text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that saves data from a simple program on our Shop Floor.  The issue I am having is that I am getting duplicate entries I beleive due to collisions with writing to the file at the same time by 2 different people

```
Do While done = 0 And attempt < 1
        done = 1
        Try

            Using theWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(ReportText, True)
                For Each currentrow As DataGridViewRow In Me.ReportGrid.Rows
                    ' The Cells are the Columns
                    For Each currentcolumn As DataGridViewCell In currentrow.Cells
                        theWriter.Write(currentcolumn.Value & vbTab)
                    Next
                    theWriter.WriteLine()

 Me.ReportGrid.Rows.Remove(currentrow)'the new line added

                Next
                theWriter.Close()
            End Using
        Catch When Err.Number = 75
            wait(2000)
            done = 0
            attempt = attempt + 1
        Catch When Err.Number <> 53
            Notify()
        End Try
    Loop
```

Comment: You should remove the item from the grid after its written, because you are trying to iterate the entire grid on each attempt. It's not clear how far you get before an exception is raised.

Comment: I know your answer already, but I should say, you should not be writing directly to a text file across different PCs. You could have a dedicated service to handle concurrent requests but write synchronously. Or simply use a database, which is really the simplest solution.

Comment: Verdolino, woudl the added line work?

Comment: I don't have your code, you tell me

Comment: I edited it in the intial question (see above)

Comment: Me.ReportGrid.Rows.Remove(currentrow)'the new line added

Comment: You should try it out